# pass object in ng2-dragula

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

I am using ng2-dragula to drag and drop items on angular 4.

Everything work fine, but I got a problem

I am using the following drake :

```
this._dragulaEventSubscription.add(this._dragulaService.dropModel(id)
  .subscribe(({ name, el, target, source, sibling, item, sourceModel, targetModel, sourceIndex, targetIndex }) => {
    console.log({ name, el, target, source, sibling, item, sourceModel, targetModel, sourceIndex, targetIndex });
  })
);
```

The item I move, but also the column source and target are big angular object with properties I do need.

The service return item I move (the object not an HTML element) but source and target are the DOM element of the column I drag to.

I would like the service to return my source and target angular4 object.

How can I bind it to work?
should I set random ID to all columns, and then get their ID in code ?

Comment: Better assign a progressive ID than a random one. Anyway you could store the column information before the drag adding a `(click)="theFunction(column)"`

Comment: that is also true, but I will still not know the target. But yes, I think I ll go with the id solution. I'll add some uid() and use a map to retrieve the columns

Comment: If I understood right, *target* is something that dragula pass in the subscription so I don't think you can intercept that *before* the subscription itself